# Objects and threads interaction modelling

Tags: multithreading, object, uml

I am trying to find a way to adequately model the interaction between objects and the threads they are running on.  I have tried a sequence diagram but the interactions are not clear enough.
What is the best way to model object and thread interaction?

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/120859/uml-diagrams-of-multi-threaded-applications

Comment: You might want to be more precise about what you cannot express in a sequence diagram, because it is indeed the good choice to model thread-interaction